# Summation formula for dynamic cells

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I want to get the sum of data from MySQL that was exported to an Excel file using PHPExcel but all I can search was summation for row. I want something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this in phpexcel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer when I continuously to google it, this the code that worked for me:

```
try{
        $sqry = $con->prepare("SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(WrkHrs))) AS MHrsTotal, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Overtime))) AS MOvtTotal,
        SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TotalOT))) AS GMTotal FROM actualot WHERE EmpID = :id AND ValidDate BETWEEN DATE(:start) AND
        DATE(:end) GROUP BY EmpID ORDER BY ValidDate ASC");
        $sqry->bindParam(':id',$rs['EmpID']);
        $sqry->bindParam(':start',$from);
        $sqry->bindParam(':end',$to);
        $sqry->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
```